# Is there a ZIP code I can enter when paying-at-the-pump in the USA with a South Korean credit card?

Tags: usa, tips-and-tricks, automobiles, payment-cards, south-korea

Im trying to use my South Korean Visa credit card at the gas pump and it is asking for my zip code. What am I supposed to do? Is there a generic ZIP code I can use?

Comment: I would suggest editing your post so it contains an actual question. Include details about the problem. At the moment it isn't even clear what country you are currently in or what the exact problem is.

Comment: Also, the tag "visas" refers to the travel documents that some people need to enter some countries, not to the credit card network.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 As far as I'm aware, only the USA calls its postal codes "zip codes".

Comment: Duplicate of this question: [Is there a ZIP code I can enter when paying-at-the-pump in the USA with a foreign credit card?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11594/32134) but **DO NOT VOTE TO CLOSE** as there is no answer for South Korean Visa cards.

Comment: @mts The question is still a duplicate, and should be closed as one. We should collect all the answers in one place: it's much better to have a question that lists all known answers than to have South Korea covered by this question, and other countries covered by the other one.

Comment: I see your point but the close reason says "This question has been asked before and **already has an answer**." (emphasis mine) which **in this case is just not true!** So I suggest to leave this post open until the South Korean credit card case has been answered in the general post and then and only then close it as a dupe! Closing it now will not help the OP nor create an incentive to post new answers for this special case. That's my 2 cent in this. @DavidRicherby

Comment: @mts I could create 150+ questions on paying with a credit card of each country on Earth then. Voting to close as dupe.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Since the poster is using a South Korean credit card we can assume he is not a native English speaker. Non-native speakers often learn both American and British english mixed in with each other, so we can't assume anything about any country.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 Fair point but it's very likely the asker said "zip code" because those are the exact words used by the machine. Also, I doubt any European country would ask for a postal code rather than the card's PIN. It's not guaranteed that the asker is in the USA but it's overwhelmingly the most likely and they can always post a correction.

Comment: @JonathanReez 40,000 posts, since there are closer to 200 countries and you could be trying to use your credit card from country A to buy petrol in country B for any pair of them.

Comment: What is wrong with having 200 extra posts, or even 40,000? In the modern searchable world, why be stingy with questions - are we trying to save a few megabytes of server space? There is currently no mechanism (other than expensive bounties) to attract attention to an old question, and so if the old question doesn't have info on South Korea, chances are it will stay this way. So we're creating a negative experience for the question-asker... in the name of what, exactly?

Comment: Related discussion on Meta: [Adding detail to existing “encyclopedic” questions - a proposal](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3779/32134)

Comment: @JonathanReez But you wouldn't, unless you were experiencing some kind of breakdown. What's wrong with the Q&A model? People ask when they need to know, and hopefully get answers in time for their trip. The countries people are interested in get answers. The others don't get asked about until someone needs to know. Better than expecting people unrealistically to fill one question with 150 countries, which will obviously never happen.

Comment: @EugeneO Because any of those hundreds of posts can be wrong or become obsolete. Having a single canonical question means there's only one place that needs to be maintained and updated, instead of hundreds of questions spread across the site.

Comment: @zach but that question *isn't* being updated, is it? It's a mess where the real answers seem to be buried in comments and other countries' answers. The country specific content is invisible to people browsing country tags. Other SE sites don't have a problem updating old questions, why do we need to be different?